# Datareader sorting?

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe, analytics, datareader

I'm new to python and would appreciate some answers which I can't seem to be able to find pertaining to pandas datareader sorting. it's also my first time posting here.

When I pull data from datareader with a specific column, it automatically puts it into a dataframe and sort in alphabetically and descending order. However, sometimes my data is sorted in ascending order. Is there a sorting rule? I know this as I plot my graphs based on iloc[0]. So, if the data is flipped, it's immediately obvious.

From what I've been told, sorting in ascending order is a 'exemplary' practice and hence, I use a for loop to guarantee this. I've checked through many finance data analysis and they don't do this. Watched some YouTube videos and their data seems to be in ascending order too. I'm so confused.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but since the data is always sorted in aphetically order, when I assign weights, I have to also do it in that order regardless of the order in my list?

Here is a simple sample code to show what I mean

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stocks = ['AAPL','MSFT','AMZN','TSLA']
data = wb.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo', '2012-1-1')['Adj Close']

norm_data = data / data.iloc[-1] * 100
norm_data.plot(figsize = (15,6))
plt.show()
```

For loop

```
stocks = ['AAPL','MSFT','AMZN','TSLA']

data = pd.DataFrame()

for s in stocks:
    data[s] = wb.DataReader(s, 'yahoo', '2012-1-1')['Adj Close']

norm_data = data / data.iloc[0] * 100
norm_data.plot(figsize = (15,6))
plt.show()
```

I have to use `data.iloc[-1]` instead of `data.iloc[0]` since the order is flipped.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this

```
stocks = ['BSE/BOM532454','BSE/BOM532822','BSE/BOM500108']
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for s in stocks:
    mydata[s] = web.DataReader(s,data_source='quandl', start='2014-1-1', api_key='YOUR_API_KEY')['Close']

mydata = mydata.sort_values(by='Date')
```